# Codeigniter userdata login session to make it available for all model/controller functions

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have this login function in controller :

```js
public function members() {
            if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in')){
                redirect('pag/index');    
            }else{
                redirect('main/restricted');
            }
```

My index will load, but my model/controllers functions won't load because of the user session.
I read about doing a MY_controller in the core, mine looks like this :

```js
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

require(APPPATH.'/libraries/HttpResponse.php');

class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {
    private $_additional_css = array();
    private $_additional_js = array();

    function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }    
    public function is_logged_in($user=true)
    {
        $user = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
        return isset($user);
     }
}
```

But it wont work, any idea?

Comment: use hook for user login session so that it can be available for all your controller & model.

Comment: I read the documentation about hooks, but I know how exactly my array and  where should I put that hook? I did enable the hook in the config.

Answer (score 0):

make changes in login controller function :-

pass exact session parameter that you set in your session

```
 public function is_logged_in('user_data')
{
    $user = $this->session->userdata('user_data');
    return $user;
 }
```

after this make changes in MY_conroller:-
 pass variable parameter in **is_logged_in** function

```
public function is_logged_in($user_data)
{
    $user = $this->session->userdata($user_data);
    return $user;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Enable hook in config.php

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

write following code into application/config/hooks.php  file

```
$hook['post_controller'] = array(
        'class'    => 'MyClass',
        'function' => 'Myfunction',
        'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
        'filepath' => 'controller',
        'params'   => ''
);
```

and last step is Create myclass.php controller in your controller folder

```
  class myclass extends CI_Controller
{
   function myfunction()
  {
     if($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in'))
      {
                redirect('pag/index');    
      }
     else
      {
                redirect('main/restricted');
      }   
  }
}
```